# How can I change code

Tags: java

Hi I want modified this code. I don't want using Collector. How I can do this

```
 Files.lines(Paths.get("tekst.txt"))
            .map(line -> line.toLowerCase().replaceAll("\\s+", " "))
            .flatMap(line -> Arrays.stream(line.split("[\\.!?]")))
            .map(sentence -> Arrays.stream(sentence.split(" "))
                            .filter(word -> unicodeWord.matcher(word).matches())
                            .map(Word::new)
                            .collect(Collectors.toList())
            )
            .filter(list -> list.size()>0)
            .map(Sentence::new)
            .map(converter::convert)
            .forEach(System.out::print);
```

and

```
class CSVConverter implements Converter{

@Override
public String convert(Sentence sentence){
    return sentence.getWords().stream().map(Object::toString).collect(Collectors.joining(","))+"\n";
```

Comment: You don't want to use a Collector, or you don't want to use the Stream API at all?

Comment: @Bubletan Collector only

Answer (score 0):

On the first one, you can do this:

```
Arrays.asList(Arrays.stream(sentence.split(" "))
    .filter(word -> unicodeWord.matcher(word).matches())
    .map(Word::new)
    .toArray(Word[]::new))
```

And on the second one:

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
sentence.getWords().stream().map(Object::toString).forEach(s -> sb.append(s).append(','));
return sb.setCharAt(sb.length() - 1, '\n').toString();
```

And the second one without Stream API:

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
for (Word word : sentence.getWords()) {
    String s = Object.toString(word);
    sb.append(s).append(',');
}
return sb.setCharAt(sb.length() - 1, '\n').toString();
```

Comment: Thank you very much!!!
Can you write me example when I don't want to use the Stream API at all?

Comment: I'll do the second one.